# Switch between triangular() and value as delayTime in assembly/delay block

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I did include two radio buttons in my simulation start window where I want to give the user the possibility to choose the delay time. It's planned to switch between the triangular() function or a simple value as a delayTime.

I already tried to create a string variable and write the triangular() function into it when the radio button is changed. Then I pass the variable to the delay time field of the delay block, but that doesnt work. If I set the variable type to double it generates a single value out of the triangular() function and passes it.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that? Ideally it should work for assembler and delay blocks.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking here. Strictly speaking the answer  to your question would be "probably...". It would be helpful if you provided your code (the one that "didn't work") and tell us what exactly should have happened and what happened instead so we can help you find the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what an option button is... such thing doesn't exist in AnyLogic, but let's assume your option button changes a variable called useTriangular, which will be equal to zero if you want a simple value and equal to 1 if you want a triangular function...

With this assumption, you can put the following code in your assembler or delay button in the delay time value:

```
useTriangular==0 ? 3 : triangular(1,2,3)
```

assuming that your simple value equals to 3... of course instead of 3, you can use a variable name if you are storing the simple value in a variable.

Comment: Sorry, AnyLogic calls them radio buttons. I had a wrong way of thinking about my problem. That appears to be exactly what I needed. Thank you!